# Comparing Numbers & process a collection of inputs

Tags: java

> Comparing one input to a known value is common enough, but you’ll often need to process a collection of inputs.
>
> Write a program that asks for three numbers. Check first to see that all numbers are different. If they’re not different, then exit the program. Otherwise, display the largest number of the three.
>
> Constraint
>
> Write the algorithm manually. Don’t use a built-in function for finding the largest number in a list.

Please see my code below. Issue I am having is the program keeps asking for numbers and it doesn't stop at 3 numbers and pull the largest number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_1_Exercise_22 {
    public static boolean contain(int[] numbs, int x) {

        for (int n : numbs)

            if (n == x)
                // Return true if connection is successful
                return true;

        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] numbs = new int[100];
        int count = 0;
        int largest = 0;

        while (true) { // make it while(count<10) for entering 10 numbers

            System.out.print("Enter any number (-1 to stop): ");

            int x = sc.nextInt();

            if (x == -1)

                break;

            if (contain(numbs, x)) {

                System.out.println("Number already entered. Please enter a different number!");

                continue;

            }

            numbs[count++] = x;

            largest = Math.max(x, largest);

        }

        System.out.println("The largest number is " + largest);

        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: You have a `count` parameter. How would you use that to stop accepting inputs after three numbers? (hint: `break`)

Answer (score 0):

Use
while(count<3)
Instead of
while(true)

Comment: If it has solved your issue, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted answer. Thank you.